# Cannot set default browser to Seamonkey

Tags: default-programs

I have set Seamonkey as default browser within Seamonkey and under preferred applications.

Yet apps that have a help section always use Firefox to go to their help website.

Any way to stop that?

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
There is only one alternative in link group `x-www-browser`
(providing `/usr/bin/x-www-browser`): `/usr/bin/firefox`.
Nothing to configure.
```

- Ubuntu-Mate 16.04 LTS Xenial
- Mate Desktop

Update in response to request:

```
update-alternatives --get-selections | grep -i browser
gnome-www-browser auto /usr/bin/firefox  infobrowser auto
/usr/bin/info  x-www-browser auto /usr/bin/firefox
```

Comment: Complaints regarding moderation do not belong inside a question; I removed it. If this is marked as a duplicate take it up at Meta ( https://meta.askubuntu.com/ ) if you disagree. By the way: BUGS are also off topic.

Comment: What does `update-alternatives --get-selections | grep -i browser` show?

Comment: update-alternatives --get-selections | grep -i browser                                                           
gnome-www-browser              auto     /usr/bin/firefox
infobrowser                    auto     /usr/bin/info
x-www-browser                  auto     /usr/bin/firefox

Comment: @fixit7 Please, when providing additional info related to your question, edit the question rather than posting it as a comment. This allows someone reading the question to see all info in one place. I have done that for you here.

Comment: duplicates as defined here on Stack Exchange are not necessarily by the same author, but as per [Messages to close voters in questions: are they OK?](//meta.askubuntu.com/a/16889) and precedent it is acceptable to make a comment in your post as to why it is not a duplicate, for example, the answers to the suggested post do not solve your problem. How did you install Seamonkey?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I kept plugging away and trying different things.

I found a fix.

I used this

```
gksu synaptic-pkexec
```

instead of

```
synaptic-pkexec
```

Now when I click on Visit homepage within synaptic, it uses Seamonkey instead of Firefox.